# Error “Only valid bearer authentication supported” when requesting access token from Spotify

Tags: python, api, spotify

I'm trying to get an authorisation access token from Spotify, but am receiving a `400` status response.
I believe I'm sending all the required parameters, as [described in their docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/):

```
def getAccessToken(ClientID, ClientSecret):

    client_creds = f"{ClientID}:{ClientSecret}"
    client_creds_b64=base64.b64encode(client_creds.encode())
    # base64.b64encode(client_creds_b64)
    client_creds.encode().decode()

    aut_token = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials"
    }

    aut_header = {
        "Authorization" : f"Basic {client_creds_b64.decode()}"
    }

    req = requests.post(authURL, data=aut_token, headers=aut_header)
    # print(req.json())
    resToken = req.json()

    accessToken = resToken['access_token']

    return accessToken


def getPlayListTrack(token, playListID):
    playListEndPoint = f'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{playListID}'

    getHeader = {
        "Authorization":"Bearer" + token
    }

    res = requests.get(playListEndPoint, headers=getHeader)
    playListOBJ = res.json()
    return playListOBJ

# API request
token = getAccessToken(ClientID, ClientSecret)
    #print(token)
    
playListID = '4lJLQPEYFXAGTDnaFO9Z9i?si=pviz-XJwSWujFvcRr1t1Ew'
trackList = getPlayListTrack(token , playListID)
print(json.dumps(trackList,indent=2))
```

but Spotify responds with:

```
 "error": {
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Only valid bearer authentication supported"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `"Authorization":"Bearer " + token`? (I only added a space after "Bearer"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spotify API error 400: "only valid bearer authentication supported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60425737/spotify-api-error-400-only-valid-bearer-authentication-supported)